# Cloned checkbox "checked" property undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes for each day of the week with an "All" checkbox to check/uncheck all days.  My use case requires multiple sets of these checkboxes, and as I'm creating them dynamically, I used the [jQuery.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function to duplicate the set and add them to a new row; however the cloned checkboxes do not work correctly.  The OnClick event fires; but for whatever reason, I can't access the 'checked' property on any of the cloned checkboxes in Chrome.  I have tried the following methods (using the All checkbox as an example):

```
$('input[name="all"]:last').prop('checked')
$('input[name="all"]:last')[0].checked
$('input[name="all"]:last').attr('checked')
```

All return undefined.  The only method I have found that actually returns anything with regards to the checked state is:

```
$('input[name="all"]:last').is(':checked')
```

I have the bug replicated here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfY5U/

Really hoping someone has some idea of what's going on, because I'm totally stuck :(

Comment: Put all relevant code directly in the question instead of making your question dependent on some other site.. There's not enough info here to give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part of code:

```
var new_content = $('.initial').clone()
        .removeClass('initial')
        .find(':checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).removeProp('checked');
        }).end().appendTo('fieldset');
```

You are **removing** property "checked" after cloning. So no surprised that it is undefined.
Just change

```
$(this).removeProp('checked');
```

to

```
$(this).prop('checked', false)
```

Comment: Usually the prop gets added back whenever I remove it that way; but your solution works flawlessly.  Thanks :)